# Different domain names for AzureAD and Office365

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have configured the azuread and office365 with different domain name. Like AzureAD Directory is ABC123.onmicrosoft.com and Office365 is DEF123.sharepoint.com.

I am building an Outlook add-in to test some samples, need to configure AzureAD app and grant Microsoft Graph api permission to access user data.

```
var azureADTenant = "ABC123"; // Target Azure AD tenant 
var SharePointTenant = "DEF123.sharepoint.com"; // Target Azure AD tenant 
var azureADClientID = "f4ad99db-d394-4509-9619-c747275c1796"; // App ClientID

// General settings for ADAL.JS
window.config = {
    tenant: azureADTenant,
    clientId: azureADClientID,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    endpoints: {
        graphApiUri: "https://graph.microsoft.com",
        sharePointUri: SharePointTenant,
    },
    cacheLocation: "localStorage"
};
```

Getting below error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://login.microsoftonline.com/DEF123.onmicrosoft.com/o…ient-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.10&nonce=f55459bf-7e25-418a-9805-f7094f0c1fc5'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
>   login.microsoftonline.com/DEF123.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/au…ient-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.10&nonce=f55459bf-7e25-418a-9805-f7094f0c1fc5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to proceed on this?

Comment: Granted below delegated permissions at Microsoft Graph API
a) Read User Files
b) Read User Contacts

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that your code is trying to open login.microsoftonline.com in an iframe, such as the task pane in an task pane add-in. For security reasons login.microsoftonline.com does not open in a frame. The usual way to handle authorization in an Office add-in is to use the Dialog API. See [Use the Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) and the samples it links to.